# Кидает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, frontend

```
loadMoreBtn[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    loadMore(0, 12, 24, amazingWorkContent);
})


function loadMore(btnIndx, startPoint, endPoint, content) {
    loadMoreBtn[btnIndx].classList.remove('active');
    loadBtn[btnIndx].classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(() => {
        loadBtn[btnIndx].classList.remove('active');

        if (BtnSwitch === 0) {
            for (let i = startPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
                content[i].classList.add('active');
            }
            loadMoreBtn[btnIndx].classList.add('active');

            BtnSwitch = 1;
        } else {
            for (let i = startPoint * 2; i < endPoint * 2; i++) {
                content[i].classList.add('active');
            }

            BtnSwitch = 0;
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

Выдает ошибку к строке - content[i].classList.add('active');
не понимаю почему так происходит.
При нажатии на кнопку loadMore должны подгрузиться картинки

Answer (score 2):

У вас идет запрос к элементу массива по несуществующему индексу. попробуйте поменять этот кусок кода

```
for (let i = startPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
     content[i].classList.add('active');
}
```

на этот

```
for (let i = startPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
    if(undefined !== content[i]) {
       content[i].classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большее,помогло

Comment: @125Year Если ответ помог, отметь его как правильный. Нажми галочку.